# Type mistmatch error - Pivot table filtering through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, filtering, pivot-table, type-mismatch, vba

I have been trying to get a pivot filter to work using an input box.  I stole most of the code from http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/hide-pivot-fields.htm and been applying to my spreadsheet and keep getting a Type Mismatch error that I can't figure out.  The example was built for numbers and I need to filter on text.

The error finder stops on the Evaluate function but both variables are defined as text so I think somehow it must be the Org variable..

```
Sub HideByCriteria()
Dim pt As PivotTable, pi As PivotItem
Dim Org As String
Dim strCri As String
Dim bHide As Boolean
Dim xlCalc As XlCalculation

    Set pt = Sheets("Req Posting Status").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    
        strCri = InputBox("Enter Organization" _
            & Chr(13) & "Valid Criteria Examples:" _
            & Chr(13) & "HCS-CT for all HCS-CT orgs" _
            & Chr(13) & "or CKS for any org that contains CKS", "HIDE AGE")

     If strCri = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
     strCri = Trim(strCri)
     
     pt.ManualUpdate = True
     With Application
            xlCalc = .Calculation
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
     End With

    'On Error GoTo NonValidCriteria:
    
        For Each pi In pt.PivotFields("Organization").PivotItems
            Org = pi
            bHide = Evaluate(Org & strCri)
            pi.Visible = bHide
        Next pi
     
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
    With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalc
            .ScreenUpdating = True
     End With
    
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below was tested in Excel 2003 and works perfectly fine. If you have any other questions please let me know. There was a lot of redundant code in the one posted above.

> **KISS - Keep it simple stupid.**

```
Public Sub HideMacro()
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim critera As String

critera = LCase$(Trim$(InputBox("Do you want to see HCS-CT or CKS?", "Critera", "CKS")))

If critera = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled Filter", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Information"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf critera <> "hcs-ct" And critera <> "cks" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid entry. Please try again.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry"
    Exit Sub
End If

With Sheet4.PivotTables(1)
    .ManualUpdate = True
    For Each pi In .PivotFields("Orginization").PivotItems
        pi.Visible = (LCase$(pi.Value) = critera) 'Hides other value and shows wanted value.
    Next
    .ManualUpdate = False
End With

End Sub
```